# I got 429 when I requested to Google Custom Search

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

I get HTTP error code "429" when I send a request to Google Custom Search API on "[Try this API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list)".

The response is here:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 429,
    "message": "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Queries' and limit 'Queries per day' of service 'customsearch.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:xxxxxxxxxx'.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Queries' and limit 'Queries per day' of service 'customsearch.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:xxxxxxxxxx'.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "rateLimitExceeded"
      }
    ],
    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
  }
}
```

I know the API has a limit that is 100 queries per day. But I have sent just 12 requests today. (You can see it in the image below.)

[image]

Do you know how to **lift this restriction on API without any payments**?

Answer (score 1):

Metric logs will not update realtime. To lift restriction without payment, you need to wait 24 hours.

Comment: I recieved 200 status code now. thank you.